# Splitting a div in three vertical parts

Tags: html, css

I want to split a div in html in three.
My code is as follow:

```
<div id="right" style="width: 20%; float: left;">
    some text
</div>
<div id="leftAndCenter" style="width: 70%; float: right;">
     <div id="center" style="width: 45%; float: left;">
           some other text
     </div>
     <div id="right" style="width: 45%; float: right;">
           and the last text
     </div>
</div>
```

There is a version with some longer text [here](http://jsfiddle.net/598akeLt/). I want the text on the right to start at the same height as "left" and "center", how should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this line:
`<br style="clear:both;"/>`

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten it when writing the js fiddle. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fist solution:

Remove the `<br style="clear:both;"/>` of your example

Second solution, better html:

```
<div>
   <div style="width: 20%; float: left;">foo </div>
   <div style="width: 33%; float: left;">bar</div>
   <div style="width: 33%; float: left;">biz</div> </div>
```